# the position of the pagination swiper js is not in the order of the slides

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I tried to make the pagination vertically with swiper js, but the button pagination doesn't match the order of the data list and starts from the 5th data instead of the 1st

[Following are the results of the pagination image starting from item 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wo7dn.png)

here is my react js code:

```
// Import Swiper React components
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";

// Import Swiper styles
import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/pagination";

import "./styles.css";

// import required modules
// import required modules
import { FreeMode, Scrollbar, Mousewheel, Grid, Pagination } from "swiper";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Swiper
        height={window.innerHeight}
        width={window.innerWidth}
        direction='vertical'
        freeMode={true}
        pagination={{
          clickable: true,
          type: "bullets"
        }}
        modules={[Pagination, FreeMode, Mousewheel]}
        className="mySwiper"
      >
        <SwiperSlide>Slide cek one</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide cek two </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 5</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 6</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 7</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 8</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 9</SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>
    </>
  );
}
```